# How to make an Android error message remain on the screen

Tags: android

I have a case where the user needs to fill out a form, and in case of error I need to display an error. I am able to do this like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sample Text TEEEEST :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But for some reason, after about 2 seconds, that text disappears. Is there a way to make it stay on the screen persistently?

Comment: What sort of error(s) are you checking for? Give an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toast stays transient until defined interval. If you want something persistent.

> ```
> 1) Display using dialog box, it stays there until user do something like ok.
>
> 2) Use some other TextView to display error message on error condition otherwise empty.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of a `Toast` is that it's transient.  You'll need to add some fields into your normal layout if you want finer control.